# How do I get my sites running on ports other than 80 in IIS 10?

Tags: iis, ports, iis-10

The only port I can set my site's http binding to and then successfully visit the site in a browser is port 80, using IIS 10. I get 404 errors if I try any other ports. Is there somewhere else I need to configure other port numbers in order to assign them to the site's bindings in IIS 10 and expect them to work? Can somebody give me a hint about what I'm missing here?

Comment: what is the hostname you are using ? could you give the working and non working hostnames  ? 
say http://localhost gives you success but http://localhost:8080/ gives you 404 .If some other process  or website is listening on that port with same hostname(localhost or machine name ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open your firewall to allow more than just port 80. Look at this guide here for some guidance -> [Firewall Rule](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mandi/2014/11/03/how-to-create-a-windows-firewall-inbound-rule/). (In the example port 8080 is used but use whatever port you want).

Then once you have that add the binding in IIS to listen on that port -> [IIS Port Binding](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/parvez/2016/07/27/iis-bindings/)